# Prevent keydown event javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i was just wondering is there away to prevent keydown events if or when input is in focus and typing

```js
window.addEventListener("onkeydown", keyDown, true);
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

function keyDown() {
  var e = window.event;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 188:
      runon();
      break;
    case 190:
      runoff();
      break;
    case 187:
      partyon();
      break;
    case 189:
      partyoff();
      break;
    case 192:
      leaderboard();
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="message" class="chat-input" placeholder="Enter your chat message..." maxlength="140">
```

Comment: [event.preventdefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) ?

Comment: or native js: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault (same as jquery, but in case you were wondering)

Comment: @PeanutHead `e.preventDefault()` **is** JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `e.preventDefault();` in your `default` block like this and it will serve the purpose:

```
switch (e.keyCode) {
case 188:
  runon();
  break;
case 190:
  runoff();
  break;
case 187:
  partyon();
  break;
case 189:
  partyoff();
  break;
case 192:
  leaderboard();
  break;
default:
 e.preventDefault();
```

}

Hope this helps.